# How credible is company/publisher and its version information of DLL or EXE?

Tags: windows, security, malware

This [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284258/how-do-i-set-the-version-information-for-an-existing-exe-dll) shows how to modify version information in some classes of binary files, like DLLs. I often rely on the version information as one metric (amongst many) for peace of mind that a binary is legitimate. I'm sure I'm not alone. If the "Company" or "Publisher" says "Microsoft Corporation" you probably can't be blamed for letting your guard down, at least a bit.

My question is whether this version information was *ever* considered reliable? Was I just being an idiot for thinking this is a useful bit of information?

Note: This [Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) has a high-rated answer that suggests using the fantastic utility [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) as one of the tools for detecting system problems, including malware. Worryingly, I managed to spoof Autoruns by manually editing the "Publisher" of a listed DLL from "Oracle Corporation" to "HonkyTonks"...

Comment: None of that data can be trusted unless the executable is signed and you've [verified that signature](http://stackoverflow.com/a/386606/94928).

Comment: If the file isn't signed then it doesn't matter what it says.  Which is the reason Microsoft signs everything.

Comment: So digital-signing is the answer and I should rely on version information with a large measure of scepticism. Got it, thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

As per [@heavyd comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1034699/version-information-in-dll-or-exe#comment1444206_1034699), none of that data can be trusted unless the executable is signed and you've [verified that signature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/386606/55075).

If the file isn't signed then it doesn't matter what it says.